# ipad beamer presentations

Tags: beamer, presentations, ipad

Is there a way to show in the ipad the pdf file of a beamer presentation so that the \pause command is respected? 
I tried Adobe Reader and ibooks, and pages slide from right to left. 
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  To clarify/re-state your question, are you asking for an iOS application that 'plays nice' with presentations made with `beamer`?

Comment: I am not sure this is on topic. Is the problem anything to do with how the PDFs are created? If not, it doesn't seem to have anything really to do with TeX.